# 'Get' method is returning null when called

Tags: java, get, null, set

I am trying to return the name of the user to another class I have set up, however when getName is called, null is returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Investor {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public String getName(){
    return firstName + " " + lastName;  
  }
  public void setName(int userIndex){
    ArrayList<String> firstNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> lastNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = "";


    try{
           FileReader fr = new FileReader("investments.txt");
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line.split("\\s+");
                firstNameList.add(line.split("\\s+")[3]);
                lastNameList.add(line.split("\\s+")[4]);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }

    this.firstName = firstNameList.get(userIndex);
    this.lastName = lastNameList.get(userIndex);
}
```

Comment: Debug your code or add a log to it.

Comment: What you're saying doesn't seem possible to me.  It would, worst case, return `null null`.

Comment: I agree with Daniel.  Also consider using the following code for debugging `String arr[] = line.split("\\s+");
                // debugging statements
                System.out.println (arr[3]);
                System.out.println (arr[4];
                firstNameList.add(arr[3]);
                lastNameList.add(arr[4]);`

Comment: are you missing a closing brace?